# HP ProLiant DL380 G6 RAID Controllers

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I have gained responsibility over a system utilizing several HP ProLiant DL380 servers. I would like to switch to RAID6 and use SSDs, of which we have dozens (Samsung Evo 860). Unfortunately, these SSDs are consumer level SATA devices, and the current onboard RAID controller in these DL380s, being a P410, will throttle the interface speed down to 3Gbps.

Taking all of this into consideration, could I simply purchase a newer RAID controller (like a P800) with a decent sized integrated battery backed cache to utilize these piles of SATA SSDs in a RAID6 array?

Edit: I mistakenly claimed my current RAID card is a p408i, when it is in fact a P410.

Comment: I'm curious about RAID6 and your concern with a 3Gbps interface speed.  What sorts of characteristics are you looking for the resulting array to have (speed / redundancy level / etc.)?  Do you have any hard and fast requirements?  What are you going to be using it for?

Comment: Hey Rob. We currently have several web servers, FTP servers and PHP servers residing as VMs on these machines. With these critical servers residing on these machines, coupled with the fact that I more or less fell into a dozen or so 500GB Samsung Evo 860 SSDs (SATA), I set out for a solution.

I'm looking to accomplish a few things: add a measurable amount of write/read speed for our customers, utilize RAID6 in preparation for worst case scenario hardware failure, and establish well as establish a backup server on an identical machine with the same configuration.

Comment: RAID6 might seem silly, but this whole adventure sprung from a simultaneous two-drive-failure (SAS HDD) on our previous RAID5 array, causing us to lose tons of data, of which there was no backup (I just took over, don't look at me).

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good.  I've got no qualms with RAID 6 - I use it myself in several situations.  Given that random disk access/writes dominates the performance of spinning drive RAID arrays, and that you haven't specified any particular performance concerns, I would recommend that you experiment with what you've got before buying another card (unless the existing one doesn't do RAID6 as desired).  SSD random access/writes are so ridiculously better than spinning drives that I will be surprised if it performs unacceptably.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Rob. I had originally thought about using these SSDs on the current configuration, but without any battery backed cache or "flash awareness" on the current RAID controller, I'm concerned there will be an increased risk of data corruption as time goes on. Thoughts?

Comment: Those are both valid concerns.  I'm not sure when RAID cards picked up TRIM support - I think it was pretty universal by 2016?  You'd have to look there.  Battery-backing is strongly recommended when you enable write caching - you don't want power loss to wipe out pending writes.  You can also handle that by not allowing write caching (which can be a sizable performance hit, but still not down to the level of spinning drives) or fake it with external UPS.  It's all about what trade off you want between cost / performance / reliability.

Answer (score 0):

P408i supports full transfer speed (6 gbps for SATA 3) per LANE and this RAID controller has only 8 lanes.
Newest RAID controllers are supporting full interface speed per physical link.
RAID-6 is not the best idea for consumer grade SSD's due to dual xor calculation. You'd better consider RAID-5/50/10.

Check this thread to get more feedbacks https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/263575-consumer-ssd-s-in-a-hp-proliant-server

Comment: Thank you! P408i-p seems like a great solution. Is there by chance a cheaper, slightly older alternative? Putting a ~$350 RAID card in a ten year old machine makes me cringe.